# Fetching an op from a SavedModel in TF2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to get a reference to an internal op in a saved model?

I have downloaded a saved model from tfhub and know which op I need after inspecting the `saved_model.pb` file. I'd like to get a reference to the op so I can record values during inference.

More concretely, I want to extract the op `transformer/layer_1/dropout_5/dropout/Mul:z:0` from bert:

```
max_seq_length = 128
input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                       name="input_word_ids")
input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                   name="input_mask")
segment_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                    name="segment_ids")

bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2",
                            trainable=True)

pooled_output, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])

# I think I need to add a reference to the internal op to the outputs here.
model = Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids], outputs=[pooled_output, sequence_output])
```

Answer (score 0):

- exhaustive and useful tutorial -> https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model
- Keras detailed guide to save models ->
  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize